# set image from another layout and class

Tags: java, android

hi I want to set a image that is took from camera but it's on a adapter
how can I solve it

here is Maniactivity code

```
static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;

public void camera(View view){

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        preview.setImageBitmap(photo);
        avatar1.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
}
```

but reference of the image that i want to set (it' id is avatar) is in my adapter

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_person,null);
    avatar= (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
```

how can I set it in MainActivity after line avatar1.setImageBitmap(photo);

Comment: Set your bitmap to list which you pass in your adapter. Then notifyDataSetChange in onActivityResult.